# Function INPUT not specified in application

Tags: database, hana

I would like to write a function where Input can be not specified

```
FUNCTION SCHEMA.FUNCTION_NAME (IN filter filter_Table_type)
    RETURN RESULT_TABLE_TYPE
    LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
    SQLSECURITY INVOKER AS

BEGIN
If :filter exists
then
return
select * from table where value in (select val from :filter)
else
select * from table where value
end if;
END;
```

`select * from Schema.function_name(VAR_FILTER_TABLE_TYPE);` shall return with filter

`select * from Schema.function_name();` shall return without filter

Is it possible? if yes how? If not, any suggestions?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check for whether or not the `filter` table parameter is empty or not:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SCHEMA.FUNCTION_NAME (IN filter filter_Table_type)
RETURNS RESULT_TABLE_TYPE
LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
SQL SECURITY INVOKER AS
BEGIN
   If is_empty(:filter) then
       res = select * from table 
             where value in (select val from :filter);
   else
       res = select * from table;
   end if;
   return :res;
END;
```

Comment: I will try in an hour and update you. I am afraid that Function call expects an input table before even checking if condition. I will let you know soon. Thanks Lars.

Comment: That's what you specified. The **type** of the parameter has to be a table type, but it can be empty.

Comment: `SAP DBTech JDBC: [1281]: wrong number or types of parameters in call: FILTER is not bound` this is the error :)

Comment: did you mean that the Input table can be an empty table or left empty?

Comment: I meant that you have to provide a parameter value in any case. If you don't have any values then you still have to provide an empty table of the correct format.